# Did I destroy my database by choosing to use clustered indexes?

Tags: sql-server

I know that every article about indexing says, that for clustered indexes, you only should create a clustered index on a column that gets used a lot by your queries.  Usually, my tables have an integer identity primary key column that I set a clustered index on, but I don't necessarily refer to this this column in ALL queries I ever do on this table.  Thus, have I doomed my whole database for destruction because I have a clustered index on this integer identity primary key column BUT I don't refer to this primary key column in 100% of all queries?

I am sorry if I sound dramatic here, but sometimes the articles make it sound like the situation is, if my queries do not 100% of the time make reference to a particular column in a table, then definitely DO NOT set a clustered index on this table or you will be cursed with slow database performance.

I really need some practical advice here because the databases I have created before all seem to run pretty fast, but I am getting stressed out that when I designed these tables I chose to put a clustered index on the integer identity primary key columns of these tables.  I am afraid that some day this database will just stop working and it will all because of my past decision to use a clustered index for each table.

But, let me ask you this - I just don't understand where the people who write these articles work at.  Like, what table always has a particular column referenced in EVERY query that has ever been run on the table?  I just don't really always see that kind of situation at my job.  I just don't know what to do here - after reading these articles, I have had a very stressful time thinking about my potential mistakes these past few days.  Please tell me I did not doom this database with my past ignorance.

Comment: In regards to `what table always has a particular column referenced in EVERY query that has ever been run on the table` ... hmm, but if 95% of the queries satisfy that then you'd say what?

Comment: I'd be interested to see any article that says it must "always has a particular column referenced in EVERY query that has ever been run on the table". I think if you boil down all the online advice you find it is a little less dramatic than you think.

Comment: Could you give us an example of a couple of these articles you're reading? I don't think I've ever heard this advice you're describing before.

Comment: Coffee, Nick.McDermaid, Matt Gibson:
Thank you all for your comments and help.  Rereading the articles, you are right that they do not say "every".  It was more the tone of how it is written that gave me that extreme impression.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, Clustered Index is to tell the database to physically store the data in the table sorted by the column(s) in the cluster index.  Clustered Index is almost always the primary key column of the table (I maybe wrong with the almost part). So the operations that would be slow are INSERTS/UPDATE because the system have to find the correct location to physically place your new/updated record and then have to relocate existing records by pushing everything else down from where the insert happens.

Creating a clustered index doesn't mean that you're doomed unless you do a lot of inserts/updates that change the value of the primary key column(s) which mean reordering of records when necessary.

Primary Key (clustered Index) on an Identity key column is good because this column is controlled by the system and is almost never changed once a record is created.(you're making the right choice).

If you find your queries are slow, then you can always create non-clustered index on the columns that are used in your queries.  In a non-clustered index, the sorted records are stored by reference, thus INSERT/UPDATE does not have high impacts on the database.

Comment: A primary key is not a clustered index. A clustered index is not a primary key. I wouldn't say "Clustered Index is almost always the primary key column" I'd say 'often'.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for clearing it up. As I have been using Identity columns as primary keys, and by default MS SQL make them clustered indices. So I never feel to need to create my own clustered index.

Comment: As an example: if you have a table with dates and you do a lot of queries which use ranges on dates, i.e. `MyDateField BETWEEN ADate AND AnotherDate` then you may see improved performance by creating the clustered index on the date field. It's not unique and it's not the primary key but it might just improve performance.

Comment: Doesn't this clustered index take a performance hit with INSERT/UPDATE when we have millions of records since clustered index is storing the records physically?

Comment: Yes. So you measure and understand the impact. Often the insert / update impact is negligible and the select performance is considerable. But everything is different so you make sure you measure performance and query plan before and after.

Comment: NPToita, Nick.McDermaid:
Thank you all for your comments and help.  It helps clarify things a lot.